# Using the CSS Filter Property for IE 7 & 8 for a gradient along with a background image decreased opacity of the image?

Tags: css, filter, background-image, gradient, opacity

I've added a gradient along with a background image to an element in IE 7 & 8, however the filter property seems to be changing the opacity of the background image so it's not as bright as it should be (instead of being a 1.0 opacity it's more like 0.4).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I've created a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/thebluehorse/9UEGu/) so you can try it out. (only works in IE 7-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: IE puts the filter over the background-image, so it actually is not gaining the opacity, but overlaid with gradient.

So, the only solution to this is to add an extra block with image so it would be over the block with gradient, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9UEGu/2/

If you don't want an extra `div` in your markup and not against expressions, you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9UEGu/3/